# metricbeat output kafka configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, metricbeat

I am trying to get the system metrics using metricbeat (metricbeat 5.1.1 and output the data to kafka topic)

```
output.kafka:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled: true

  # The list of Kafka broker addresses from where to fetch the cluster metadata.
  # The cluster metadata contain the actual Kafka brokers events are published
  # to.
  hosts: ["XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9092","XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9092","XX.XXX.XXX.XX:9092"]
  # The Kafka topic used for produced events. The setting can be a format string
  # using any event field. To set the topic from document type use `%{[type]}`.
  topic: ab-mb-raw, cd-mb-raw
```

Is it possible to push the data to more than one topic in kafka?

When I ran the above configuration, I am not able to see the data in the kafka topic persistent

Can anyone help me whether my config is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly as a static string, no. But you can read the comment there...

> The setting can be a format string using any event field

Thus, if you can insert a field into the payload of which topic to be sent to, you can dynamically route data that way

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do that.  Basically you will need to define in your prospectors configs.

For example:

Main **filebeat.yml**:

```
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["kafka:9092"]
  topic: "%{[type]}"   <----- that is what you need.
  compression: snappy

# Prospector configs
filebeat.config_dir: /opt/filebeat/etc/conf.d
```

Your prospectors from **/opt/filebeat/etc/conf.d** can looks something like these to files:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
paths:
  - "test.log"
document_type: "topic_name" <--------- topic per prospector
```

Comment: metricbeat is not same as filebeat. It has no document_type field!